# Does this perfect graph exist?

Tags: graph-theory

is there a perfect graph (see here for definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem ) with 24 vertices and 102 edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many such graphs exist. Here is a hint:

> Every bipartite graph is perfect.